# c++17 template deduction guide for partial specialisation - possible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Suppose I declare a class of function objects of a given arity (number of parameters), which may have between 0 and arity arguments already embedded.

Here's an example of a notional binary_op, note the template deduction guide which allows easy use of these function objects.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<class Pred, class...ArgsR>
struct binary_op
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(ArgsR) <= 2, "binary ops can have max 2 args");
    template<class P, class...As>
    binary_op(P&& p, As&&...as)
    : pred_(std::forward<P>(p))
    , args_r(std::forward<As>(as)...)
    {}

    template<class...ArgsL>
    decltype(auto) operator()(ArgsL&&...args_l) const
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(ArgsR) + sizeof...(ArgsL) == 2, 
            "binary ops must be executed with 2 args");
        return std::apply(pred_, std::tuple_cat(std::tie(args_l...), args_r));
    }

    Pred pred_;
    std::tuple<ArgsR...> args_r;
};

template<class Pred, class...ArgsR> binary_op(Pred&&, ArgsR&&...) -> binary_op<std::decay_t<Pred>, std::decay_t<ArgsR>...>;


int main()
{
    auto plus_op = [](auto&& x, auto&& y) -> decltype(auto) { return x + y; };
    auto plus = binary_op(plus_op);
    auto plus2 = binary_op(plus_op, 2);
    auto plus2_3 = binary_op(plus_op, 2, 3);

    std::cout << plus(3, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << plus2(5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << plus2_3() << std::endl;
}
```

Now I want to generalise the idea, and allow the specification of 'arity' (the number of notional arguments) as a template argument.

My first guess at writing a deduction guide for a partial specialisation (leaving the Arity template argument unspecified) was not a success so I resorted to passing an unused `arity<N>` constructor argument:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t N>
struct arity : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> {};

template<std::size_t Arity, class Pred, class...ArgsR>
struct arity_op
{
    using overall_arity = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Arity>;

    static_assert(sizeof...(ArgsR) <= overall_arity(), "number of initial args must be less than or equal to arity");

    using function_arity = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, overall_arity() - sizeof...(ArgsR)>;

    template<class P, class...As>
    arity_op(arity<Arity>, P&& p, As&&...as)
    : pred_(std::forward<P>(p))
    , args_r(std::forward<As>(as)...)
    {}

    template<class...ArgsL>
    decltype(auto) operator()(ArgsL&&...args_l) const&
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(ArgsL) == function_arity(), 
            "arguments to functor must have correct arity");
        return std::apply(pred_, 
                            std::tuple_cat(std::forward_as_tuple(args_l...), 
                            args_r));
    }

    Pred pred_;
    std::tuple<ArgsR...> args_r;
};

template<std::size_t Arity, class Pred, class...ArgsR> arity_op(arity<Arity>, Pred&&, ArgsR&&...) -> arity_op<Arity, std::decay_t<Pred>, std::decay_t<ArgsR>...>;


int main()
{
    auto plus_op = [](auto&& x, auto&& y) -> decltype(auto) { return x + y; };
    auto plus = arity_op(arity<2>(), plus_op);
    static_assert(decltype(plus)::function_arity() == 2, "");

    auto plus2 = arity_op(arity<2>(), plus_op, 2);
    static_assert(decltype(plus2)::function_arity() == 1, "");

    auto plus2_3 = arity_op(arity<2>(), plus_op, 2, 3);
    static_assert(decltype(plus2_3)::function_arity() == 0, "");

    std::cout << plus(3, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << plus2(5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << plus2_3() << std::endl;
}
```

What I think I want is to be able to write:

```
auto plus = arity_op<2>(plus_op); // arity specified as a template argument
```

Is it possible to write a deduction guide for a such a partial specialisation?

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067388/will-template-parameter-deduction-for-constructors-available-since-c17-allow-e

Comment: Does this work?  `arity<2>::op(plus_op)`, with `arity` a class template and `op` a nested class template with deduction guide